# path: null in DEBUG output for http module, even after explicitly passing path in options

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Was getting 401 error for a http get request with `http` module from nodeJS.

To Debug this set `NODE_DEBUG=http,https` (context: because I was able to to a get call for the same in Postman wanted to know why 401 for same credentials).

While going through the debug output found out that the path in the options is `null`.

debug output:

```
HTTP 22812: call onSocket 0 0
HTTP 22812: createConnection some.thing.com:8000: [Object: null prototype] {
  method: 'GET',
  host: 'some.thing.com',
  port: 8000,
  path: null,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Basic encoded_key:secret_;)_'
  },
  timeout: 60000,
  noDelay: true,
  servername: 'some.thing.com',
  _agentKey: 'some.thing.com:8000:'
}
```

passed options is as follows:

```
_config = {
           method: 'GET',
           host: "some.thing.com",
           port: 8000,
           path: `/I/do/have/a/path`,
           headers: _headers,
           timeout: timeOut
         };
```

can anyone let me know is this normal to see `null` in debug output.

Because if in actual the `path` was sent out as null I should have received a `404:NOT_FOUND` error from server and not `401:Unauthorized` error right!?

Comment: I also just saw this, did you ever work it out?

Comment: @Hugo that undefined `path` is something I am still getting, but my issue was resolved by correcting the token url that I was using to generate the token

Comment: Ok thanks, it’s the null path that I’m struggling with.

Comment: @Hugo you can elevate here https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4082 I had filed this issue